# How can I retrieve a Trello Board's shortLink from a card page?

Tags: trello, javascript

I'm making a Google Chrome extension for Trello, and want to get the `shortLink` of the current Board, *while viewing a Card URL*.

For example:

This card https://trello.com/c/v9eqAHMX/20-api-documentation

Belongs to this board https://trello.com/b/nPNSBZjB/trello-resources

If the current page is the board then I can extract the `shortLink` (**nPNSBZjB** in this case) from `window.location.pathname`. But if the current page is a card, is it possible to retrieve the board's `shortlink` using javascript?

Keeping track of the last board URL that was visited works in most cases, but not when a user lands directly on the card URL (without going via the board).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet will be to use the card's shortLink to make a few API requests.  Using [this route](https://trello.com/docs/api/card/index.html#get-1-cards-card-id-or-shortlink-list-field), you can get the board's long id from the card's shortLink.  If you need the `shortLink` (the `id` would, for most purposes, suffice), you can use the id and [this route](https://trello.com/docs/api/board/index.html#get-1-boards-board-id-field).

There are ways to do it synchronously, but they will be very fragile and prone to breaking on client updates, so I would not recommend them.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I'm currently using the API as you suggested. It certainly works, but is a bit slow, which is why I'm hoping I can scrape it somehow instead. I do see what you mean about any other solution being somewhat fragile, though.

Comment: Both "this route" links go to 404 pages.

Comment: @JerryWaller Trello has completely re-done their API docs and is not serving redirects to accommodate old links. There should be enough information in the links to find the new docs page if you're interested in updating this answer.